# BeautifulSoup4 stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, python3

Using BeautifulSoup4 on Python3

Fired up my Ubuntu machine and got the following error.  My web scraping script runs BeautifulSoup4 and was working so far.   The only thing I did recently was install Audacity. Don't know how that could affect BeautifulSoup.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrubNprint.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'
```

The error `from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup`, I have searched my directory list and I don't seem to find the script `builder`.

The error `from . import _html5lib`, the file seems to be there in the directory `bs4/builder`.  I don't understand why I am getting this error.

The last error

```
class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'
```

is unclear to me. It appears to be in the script.

More importantly, I did not touch anything that I know of. But I might have done an update before installing Audacity.  However, I don't think updating Ubuntu should have affected BeautifulSoup.

When I do  `pip3 --user uninstall beautifulsoup4`  I get a message that `--user` is invalid.

I did `pip uninstall`, then tried a reinstall.  Still getting the same error messages.

beautifulsoup is installed.   the results of the command you asked for is;

```
python-bs4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.4.1-1
  Version table:
     4.4.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
python3-bs4:
  Installed: 4.4.1-1
  Candidate: 4.4.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

My python code is correct.  it was working for 5 months.  then, all of sudden I got the traceback error above.  which has not gone away, after deleting and reinstalling beautifulsoup (see [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/beautifulsoup/module$20$27html5lib.treebuilders$27$20has$20no$20attribute$20$27_base$27/beautifulsoup/JO_9ufJB4UM/ZTiIF6zmAAAJ).

There is a bug in the current release of the `html5lib` that causes the error, and it should be fixed in a few weeks.

Comment: How did you install BeautifulSoup4? How are you invoking it and in what (Python) environment?

Comment: i'm using python3 from the command line.  in a terminal.

Comment: don't remember how i had initially installed beautifulsoup but, i tried reinstalling with both apt-get & pip install   both worked and told me that an valid installation was already installed.

Comment: I did make one other change to my machine.  don't know how, if at all this would affect beautifulsoup.  i installed curl.

Comment: Could you please remove the `pip` package (`sudo pip3 uninstall beautifulsoup4` and `pip3 --user uninstall beautifulsoup4`)? Having two instances of the same package on the path is asking for trouble. Then, could you please reinstall the Apt package (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-bs4`) and try again? Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @karel i did the pip3 uninstall as suggested, followed by the apt-get.  that didn't help.

Comment: yes.  beautifulsoup is installed.  my code was working fine for 5 months.  then all of sudden died with the tracebacks above.  and, i deleted beautifulsoup and reintalled and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @karel see this link:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/beautifulsoup/module$20$27html5lib.treebuilders$27$20has$20no$20attribute$20$27_base$27/beautifulsoup/JO_9ufJB4UM/ZTiIF6zmAAAJ    there is a bug in beautifulsoup that will soon be patched.

Comment: @ karel.  ok.  but, an fyi if anyone else is having the problem, just remove the underscore in "treebuilders._base" in "_html5lib.py"

Comment: @karel don't know how to ping, unless this is pinging, but i don't know it.  :-)  i do think it appropriate to have  "remove the underscore in "treebuilders._base" in "_html5lib.py" as an answer . true this is a beautifulsoup bug. but, it started with apt-get update installing this bug.  i can't be the only one with the problem. it would save some ppl a headache.